# Display Drop Down Selection Name in IMG URL

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

How would I dynamically update the end part of an img URL based on a drop down selection?
for example when blue is selected the filename before .jog would get filled in with the word blue. It's using a css and I can't add any ids to the :

```
<img src="www.mysite.com/blue.jpg">

<select>
  <option>green</option>
  <option>blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').change(function(){
       var src = $(':selected', this).text()
       $('img').attr('src', location.hostname + "/" + src + '.jpg');
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(':selected', this).text();` can be `$(this).val()`

Comment: @undefined: because you didn't voted that up despite being a good answer.

Comment: @refhat How do you know? I _did_.

Comment: I get the following error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'change' of null "

Comment: Sorry. That was a dumb mistake by me. So I'm no longer getting an error from your script, but my urls are showing "www.mysite.com/.jpg" They are not getting adjusted by the script. Could it because I have multiple select boxes and multiple images?

Comment: @undefined it was conflicted with another script so I changed it to: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('select').change(function(){
       jQuery('img').attr('src', location.hostname + "/" + this.value + '.jpg')
    })
})`

Comment: @undefined bingo! only issue now is that it's pulling the value from inside <select value=> not the text from inbetween <select> and </select>

Comment: @SamDanger Or open a new question and let me know.

Comment: @undefined if instead of <img src="www.mysite.com/blue.jpg"> I want to use <img src="<?php my php code for url ?>/selectname.jpg"> how would I adjust script?

Comment: @SamDanger You can instead of `location.hostname` `echo` the url.

Comment: @undefined I just opened a new question for that.. thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229722/using-jquery-to-adjust-a-dynamic-url

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var $img = $('img'), $select = $('select').on('change keyup', function() {
    $img.attr('src','http://www.mysite.com/' + $select.find(':selected').html() + '.jpg')'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $('select').change(function () {
    $(this).parent().attr('src', location.hostname + "/" + this.val() + '.jpg');
  });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to effect the url whatsoever.

Comment: @SamDanger: is your html exactly the way you have mentioned in the question. If not then t wont work. because it looks for parent as img tag.

Comment: My actual HTML is much more complicated, it's running multiple imgs/selects through a loop via magento. but the img tag is there.

Comment: @SamDanger: you accepted the answer. looks like issue is solved now.